# What was so good about the 19th Century Osage police?

Tags: 19th-century, native-americans, old-west, law-enforcement

I was recently directed to an article written by Historian [Art Burton](https://www.artburton.com/) for a police publication about [policing in late 19th Century Indian Territory](http://lestweforget.hamptonu.edu/page.cfm?uuid=9FEC4BE4-0CFE-0ACA-15B57C52CED4B765). I got interested in this due to a family story about having a couple of full-blood Osage uncles who were US Marshals under "Hanging Judge" Isaac Parker.

With that Osage connection, this line in the article stuck out for me:

> Outside of the Five civilized Tribes in the Indian Territory there
> were also Indian policemen of note. The Osage Agency located at
> Pawhuska had a very good police department.

I didn't see any further detail on this in the article, and I'd very much like some.

It did mention much later (early 20th Century) a somewhat famous policeman Wiley Haines, who I can find a very few bits of info online about, and that the Dalton brothers (of [Dalton Gang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalton_Gang) fame) were for a time in the force's employ. But of course the former of these was later, and the latter of the two doesn't exactly speak good things about the enforcement body in question.

Comment: A report [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=7ZQ6AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA260&dq=Osage+Agency+located+at+Pawhuska+had+a+very+good+police+department&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj5itaOzJv0AhVXFzQIHaWbC5gQ6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=Osage%20Agency%20located%20at%20Pawhuska%20had%20a%20very%20good%20police%20department&f=false) from 1896 mentions some the the agencies law enforcement and court activities, but it gives no indication if this was *very good* or not.

Comment: Why don't you ask Burton for details?

Comment: @kimchilover -  I did check to see if he's on Twitter, but it doesn't appear he is. He's got a book, [Black, Red, and Deadly](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/14668.Black_Red_and_Deadly) that may well have more info on this. Its on my list now, but Christmas is sooooo far off.

Comment: WHy not use https://www.artburton.com/contact ?

Comment: @kimchilover - Hmmm. Perhaps I'll do that if the info isn't in his book. (Who puts their cell # on the internet? Yikes!)

Comment: I suspect it's not unrelated that the Osage experienced an oil boom and an associated [murder spree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osage_Indian_murders) in the 1920s. Whether or not the Osage Agency really was "a very good police department" (whatever that means), I would speculate that they might have been better funded then most other native police agencies, at least for a time.

Comment: @BrianZ - That's could be an explanation in the 1920's, but it looks like [the first commercially productive oil well in the territory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Oil_Well_in_Oklahoma) wasn't until 1897. (should I add this info in the question?)